# How to keep app files in Genymotion between debug sessions

Tags: android, genymotion

In my app I download some files in **/data/data/com.myapp.myappandroid/files**. The problem is that when I debug with Genymotion and restart the app, **/data/data/com.myapp.myappandroid/files** is cleaned and I have to download the files again. Is there a way to set Genymotion to not delete the files in **/data/data/com.myapp.myappandroid/files**?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This should not happen.

When you creates a private file it should not be deleted until you delete it yourself or you uninstall the app explicitly.

So I advise you to verify that the deletion is not done by mistake. And if you don't solve your problem, please give a precise list of manipulation to reproduce the problem.

Comment: It happens. I use VisualStudio with Xamarin plug-in for debugging. I just found out that there is a setting in VisualStudio that tells Genymotion to keep the old files. Probably something to do with the command line parameters passed.

Comment: Yes this may enable an `adb install -r` command instead of uninstall/install app